# Beginner C#.NET error: If args doesn't have a length why is my book writing it as such?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005

I recently started learning C#.NET and have been using Visual Studios 2005 as my IDE. I copied this code straight out of the textbook and it gives me the the error below.            The output I am suppose to receive is: Please enter a numeric argument: 1
Yet I get this error: Since ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(string[])' returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if(args.Length == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a numeric argument: ");
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio / C# is the book aimed at? For that matter, which book was it?

Comment: Yeah, and even a beginner should try reading the error message. It is quite clear it has nothing to do with "args" but with the return keyword. It says so right in the error message. Care to read it, please.

Comment: It is c# your visual blueprint for building .NET applications by Eric Butow and Tommy Ryan.

Comment: Look at the book again.  Carefully compare the declaration of Main() in the book with yours.

Comment: @HansPassant From reading the reviews, I strongly suspect that OP has typed it out correctly.

Answer (score 5):

This is because you had `Main` marked as `void`. This means it would only expect you to call `return`. If you want to return an exit code, as in your example, then you need to change your `Main` method to return an `int`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        // Make this int instead of void
        static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            if(args.Length == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a numeric argument: ");
                return 1;
            }

            // Default return value
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't compile since not all code paths return a value.  A return statement must be added outside of the if statement as well.

Comment: @Kyle - You're right and I missed that in my haste to post! :-) I have added default return value.

Answer (score 4):

You are returning some value to a method which return type is VOID.

As documented in official site http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yah0tteb.aspx :-

> When used as the return type for a method, void specifies that the
>   method doesn't return a value.

Make your method as below

```
static int Main(string[] args)
{
    ////Your code
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Reviews for this book can be found at [http://www.amazon.com/visual-blueprint-building-applications-Software/dp/076453601X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/076453601X); it has an average rating of 1.9 out of 5, and comments include:

> I thought it was a beginner book, maybe the pics are but the code [is bad]. Doesn't explain any of the examples very well. Not a very good book.

and

> Wow!!! This book is really badly written.

Sadly, the code quoted is another example of this. A `void` method is one that doesn't return a value, so to have defined `main` as `void` and then returned a value is completely incorrect.

I would recommend recycling your current book into a set of firelighters, and then buying a decent book to replace it.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want it to display the message and do nothing else then it should be:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if(args.Length == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a numeric argument: ");
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Remove "1" after return.

Comment: Not true. You are missing the error code return value now.

Comment: Its void hence it doesn't want any value passed back hence you just return with any value.

Comment: Usually returning -1 indicates an error. Much used in old batch scripts.

Comment: @PatrickHofman this is not batch script. You want an error? throw an `Exception`

Comment: I am just trying to explain returning an int is useful. That's all. Removing it is a bad idea. Changing the return type is better.

Comment: Your approach does not mean his is wrong. Happy reading: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7729659/837623

Comment: It *is* a solution, but not the better one.

Comment: It really depends on what you really want to do. If you just want to display the message and do nothing then removing "1" would do the trick.